# Processing vec in parallel: how to do safely, or without using unstable features?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, unsafe

I have a massive vector that I want to be able to load/act on in parallel, e.g. load first hundred thousand indices in one thread, next in another and so on. As this is going to be a very hot part of the code, I have come up with this following proof of concept unsafe code to do this without Arcs and Mutexes:

```
let mut data:Vec<u32> = vec![1u32, 2, 3];
let head = data.as_mut_ptr();
let mut guards = (0..3).map(|i|
  unsafe {
    let mut target = std::ptr::Unique::new(head.offset(i));
    let guard = spawn(move || {
      std::ptr::write(target.get_mut(), 10 + i as u32);
    });
    guard
  });
```

Is there anything I have missed here that can make this potentially blow up?

This uses `#![feature(unique)]` so I don't see how to use this in stable. Is there a way to do this sort of thing in stable (ideally safely without using raw pointers and overhead of `Arc`'s and `Mutex`'s)?

Also, looking at  [documentation for `Unique`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html), it says

> It also implies that the referent of the pointer should not be modified without a unique path to the `Unique` reference

I am not clear what "unique path" means.

Comment: Could `Vec.split_at_mut(..)` work for you?

Comment: you can split it mutably but you are still stuck with how to move ownership into the worker threads and then get it back. i don't see how to do this safely since while the worker threads are computing, in the parent thread you still have mutable access to the original vec. there are lifetime issues too as the closure may escape the block, unboxed closures may fix that - i don't know much about them though.

Comment: once [`scoped`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) gets a proper replacement `split_at_mut` is the correct solution. Until then I suggest simply creating multiple vectors, one for every thread.

Comment: `chunks_mut` is a nicer version of `split_at_mut` for this purpose: `for target in data.chunks_mut(100_000) { ... }`.

Comment: Maybe this approach is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851207/286335

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Today the [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) crate is the de facto standard for this sort of thing:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    data.par_iter_mut()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(i, x)| *x = 10 + i as u32);
    assert_eq!(vec![10, 11, 12], data);
}
```

Note that this is just one line different from the single-threaded version using standard iterators, which would replace `par_iter_mut` with `iter_mut`.

See also [Writing a small ray tracer in Rust and Zig](https://nelari.us/post/raytracer_with_rust_and_zig/).

Comment: How can you limit parallelism with this (like do not make more than 4 API requests at a time while iterating over a list of requests to make)?

Comment: @BrandonRos https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-many-threads-will-rayon-spawn

Answer (score 8):

One can use an external library for this, e.g. [`simple_parallel`](https://crates.io/crates/simple_parallel) (disclaimer, I wrote it) allows one to write:

```
extern crate simple_parallel;

let mut data = vec![1u32, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let mut pool = simple_parallel::Pool::new(4);

pool.for_(data.chunks_mut(3), |target| {
    // do stuff with `target`
})
```

The [`chunks`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) and [`chunks_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) methods are the perfect way to split a vector/slice of `T`s into equally sized chunks: they respectively return an iterator over elements of type `&[T]` and `&mut [T]`.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Though I'd like to sort out all the details of this myself, so I can learn. I hadn't thought of doing this using channels. I will need to think about this some more.

Comment: I rolled my own with https://github.com/rust-lang/threadpool .  http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/finding-closure-in-rust/ was very helpful.