# Is it possible to access disjoint slices with multiple threads using only std?

Tags: multithreading, rust

It's been previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818141/how-do-i-pass-disjoint-slices-from-a-vector-to-different-threads) whether disjoint slices can be accessed by multiple threads. The answer is the crossbeam crate, which provides a lot of functionality.

Is it possible to do this *without* the use of a third party crate? If I have a vector or array, can I split it into multiple slices and have a different thread operate on each slice using only the features provided by the standard library?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928205/1411457) answer would help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can different threads write to different sections of the same Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928051/can-different-threads-write-to-different-sections-of-the-same-vec)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread)

Comment: Summary of the duplicate: no. `std` does not expose an API that allows stack references to be shared between threads. There is also `scoped-threadpool` which is considerably smaller in scope than `crossbeam`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) or [`chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) helps.